# Jersey + Spring standalone webservice @Autowire not working

Tags: java, spring, jersey, spring-boot

I am running Restful web-service as standalone application using Jersey.

Below are my service classes which serve's the requests.

**LoginServiceImpl.java**

```
@Component
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

@Value("${login.service.defaultmessage}")
private String defaultMessage;

@Autowired
private EmLoginDAO emLoginDAO;

@Override
public String defaultCall() {
    return defaultMessage;
}

@Override
public String updatePassword(List<Login> userList) {
    System.out.println(emLoginDAO + "\n" + userList);
    emLoginDAO.save(userList);
    return "Passwords Updated...";
}

@Override
public List<Login> getPasswords() {
    System.out.println("OBJECT: " + emLoginDAO);
    List<Login> userList = null;
    userList = emLoginDAO.findAll();
    return userList;
}
}
```

**LoginService.java**

```
@Component
@Path("/user")
public interface LoginService {

@GET
public String defaultCall();

@POST
@Path(value = "/print")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String updatePassword(List<Login> userList);

@GET
@Path(value = "/getpassword")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Login> getPasswords();
}
```

Below is my spring configuration file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.em.login" />
<context:annotation-config />
```

After starting the service when I call the respective method get called.

But my **defaultMessage** and **emLoginDAO** objects are null. So it is not referring to the properties and spring configuration files.

So can any one please help me to get this correct. Or to find a way to set the properties and spring configuration file paths to Jersey.

**Update**

```
Closeable server = null;
        try {
            DefaultResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(
                    LoginServiceImpl.class);
            resourceConfig.getContainerResponseFilters().add(
                    new GZIPContentEncodingFilter());
            server = SimpleServerFactory.create(serviceurl,
                    resourceConfig);


            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how do you publish your service?

Comment: I have updated the questing with the code. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working.

Referred the [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#deployment.classpath-scanning) part of the Jersey documentation.

Below is the code I have used to make this working.

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(LoginServiceImpl.class);
resourceConfig.register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.UriConnegFilter.class);
resourceConfig.register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider.class);
resourceConfig.property(ServerProperties.METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, true);
resourceConfig.property("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:/spring-config.xml");

URI serviceUri = UriBuilder.fromUri(serviceHost).port(servicePort).build();
server = SimpleContainerFactory.create(serviceUri, resourceConfig);
```

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the culprit:
`DefaultResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(LoginServiceImpl.class);`

You are using Spring's IOC to create the objects and do the autowiring, but you are not getting the instance from the Spring container.  You need to get the LoginServiceImpl instance from the Spring container, and not have Jersey create it (Jersey does not know how to autowire your @Autowired properties.

You should use the [Spring integration with Jersey, seen here.](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#spring)

Edit to respond to your comment, you posted this code:

```
LoginServiceImpl loginServiceImpl = (LoginServiceImpl) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("loginServiceImpl"); 
DefaultResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig( loginServiceImpl.getClass());
```

You are creating a loginServiceImpl via the spring container, and I'll bet if you check your autowired fields will be there.

However, the second line where you use `loginServiceImpl.getClass()` this is going to create a *new* LoginServiceImpl, which is not  the same one as the loginServiceImpl you got from the context, so you still are going to have the same problem.

Comment: LoginServiceImpl loginServiceImpl = (LoginServiceImpl) springApplicationContext.getBean("loginServiceImpl");
                DefaultResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig(
                        loginServiceImpl.getClass());

I have changed the code as you have mentioned. But this way service is not even starting.

Comment: See my comment, you're still not using a spring managed bean in your DefaultResourceConfig - you're using a spring managed bean to get the class, but the resourceConfig is going to instantiate one itself and not use the Spring one, you need to pass your loginServiceImpl instance in, instead of the class.

Comment: But there is no constructor in **DefaultResourceConfig** class which accepts the instances of any service class.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [Microserver](https://github.com/aol/micro-server), that will do all the wiring between Jersey and Spring for you (and setup a Grizzly webserver). From the tags I notice you are using Spring boot, with Microserver: [micro-boot module](https://github.com/aol/micro-server/tree/master/micro-boot) you can do (in a class in package com.em.login):

```
   public static void main(String[] args){
     new MicrobootApp(()->"test-app").run();
   }
```

And it should wire up Grizzly, Jersey & Spring with Spring-boot enabled for any backend (non-Jax-rs) dependencies.

Alternatively without Spring Boot (plain old Jersey and Spring)

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
     new MicroserverApp(()->"test-app").run();
   }
```

To do it manually, you will need to add the Jersey-Spring integration jar to your classpath and make sure both are configured in a way that interoperates (i.e. I think a registering Spring ContextListener is essential). There is an [example app here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.19/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp).

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured those two in your spring configuration files?
I mean have you annotated EmLoginDAO also as stereotype Component?